# Minimum value of numbers in char array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I recently ran into this problem in an interview, and I was curious what the best way to solve it would be. The question is given a char array that has the ascii characters '0' to '9' make one swap such that the the set of ascii values in the resultant array forms the lowest possible value. Both the input array will not have preceding 0s and neither should the resultant array.

So here is an example: `char a[] = {'1','0', '9','7','6'}`

The solution: `char b[] = { '1','0', '6', '7', '9'}`

Another example: `char a[] = {'9','0', '7','6','1'}`

The solution:  `char b[] = {'1','0', '7','6','9'}`

I am looking for the best solution in terms of performance. Since only one swap is allowed I assumed that sorting is not allowed. I did not clarify that though.  So we are looking for the lowest possible value that can be obtained through just using one swap. It would help if you could provide the complexity of the solution as well.

Comment: That's asking for an `O(1)` sorting algorithm (lowest possible value == order the smaller digits to the positions with higher place value). Was that interviewer a high-expectation Asian dad?

Comment: I love interview questions like this, they give me an immediate pointer on whether I want to work for the muppets.

Comment: Um did they mean the lowest value, or the lowest possible value after one swap. Clarifying that would have been my first question. Would have told me if I was dealing with the swedish chef, Bert or one of the more intelligent ones.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Why are you turning this into a rant against the interviewers, when you don't even know them?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question here before. Darned if I know how to search for it.

Comment: lowest possible value from one swap is what was expected

Comment: This is an interesting question because the more you think about it, the more special cases you come across. That will be why it's asked at interviews: they're probably less interested in what answer you come up with than the approach you take to get there. How do you adjust your solution as you discover more about the problem? Are you able to find the edge cases? How do you react when they give you an example that your algorithm will fail on? It's more about the journey than the destination.

Comment: Only some one who doesn't know me would consider a mere two asides, a rant. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm:**

Note that since there can't be a leading 0, 0's should be catered for separately.

Go from the right, keeping track of the minimum non-zero number. Also record the first 0.

Whenever you find a number larger than the recorded non-zero number, record those 2 as the best possible swap so far.

Once you've found a zero, record any non-zero non-leading character from here as the best possible swap for the zero.

Note that you're not doing any comparisons between the quality of either of the swaps above, we simply replace the current best with the new one, as it's always better to swap with a more-left position.

When done, compare the target positions of the best swap for the zero and the best swap for the non-zero and pick the left-most position, or the zero if they're the same.

If no possible swap was found, the array is already the minimum permutation of the given numbers, thus don't do anything. Or, if we have to, swap the two right-most characters.

**Running time:**

`O(n)`.

**Example:**

**Input:** 10976

```
Processing  6   7   9   0   1
Minimum     6   6   6   6   1
Best swap   -   6+7 6+9 6+9 6+9
Zero?       No  No  No  Yes Yes
Best 0 swap -   -   -   -   -
```

So the best swap is 6/9, giving us 10679

**Input:** 3601

```
Processing  1   0   6   3
Minimum     1   1   1   3
Best swap   -   -   1+6 1+3
Zero?       No  Yes Yes Yes
Best 0 swap -   -   0+6 0+6
```

Here possible swaps are 1/3 and 0/6.
For the 1/3 swap, the target position is 0 (0-indexed).
For the 0/6 swap, the target position is 1.
So we pick the 1/3 swap giving us 1603.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start at the leftmost digit

While current digit is valued the lowest (non-zero for the first digits equal 
  to the number of zeroes in the set) of the remaining set of numbers, advance
  to the next number

Swap current value with lowest remaining value.
```

You can keep a sorted copy of the array to help you in your decision making process.  You'd need it for knowing how many there are of your current lowest number(s).  You can make it even more efficient if you store their indices as well.

It's not necessary to have any additional storage, but it would likely make things faster.  In a single pass of the first array, you can get the number of 0s as well as the index to the next lowest number, but in an array like 1, 0, 6, 9, 7, you would then have to go through the array 4 different times.

EDIT - slightly more flushed out algorithm

```
Copy the array into a separate one, called c, and sort c.  (You'll use this to make your decision faster, though you could simply repeatedly analyze the array.)
if c has zeros, find the value of its first non-zero value, called x
if a[0] != x, swap a[0] with x.
set index to 1
while a[index] == c[index], ++index
swap a[index] with c[index]
```

If you do it this way, it costs you another array, but is done with one sort and one pass through the array.

If you don't do it that way, you'll have to pass through the remainder of the array each time to find the minimums.  I'm not great at complexity, but I believe that's n log n, since you'll be starting from higher indices each iteration.

Without using the array, you'd have to do something like

```
Find the lowest non-zero value
if a[0] isn't this value, swap with this value
index = 1
find lowest value starting at a[index]
if they're not equal, swap the values, done.  Otherwise,  increment index
```

That's still n log n.  I think sorting can make it more efficient.

Comment: Look at the above edit I made to the question. I am not sure you can sort the array as that would involve more than one swap.

Comment: @AndroidDev93 Your edit doesn't say anything about limiting what you can do in decision making logic.  I'm not saying modify `a` or `b`, but maintain a separate `c` array.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by best.
Take out the lowest number except '0' as the first item in b, then sort the rest into ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you clearly have to go through the array at least once.  You need to do this to find the smallest value.

You also need to find the value which will satisfy the conditions.  The poster says that the input array will not have '0' as the leading elements.

We loop over the array one position at a time.  We are looking for another position which has the minimum value (non zero for the first spot, anything for the other spots) and is smaller than any other seen.

```
for (pos = 0; pos < array_size-1; pos++) {
        low_index = pos;
        min_value = (pos == 0) ? '1' : '0';

        for (i = pos+1; i < array_size; i++) {
                if (min_value <= array[i]) && (array[i] < array[low_index])) {
                        low_index = i;
                }
        }

        if (low_index != pos) {
                low_value = array[pos];
                array[pos] = array[low_index];
                array[low_index] = low_value;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: What you describe will result in *no swaps* for the OP's example since the smallest nonzero is already at the beginning. However, this is not the optimal solution.